# How to HEALTHCHECK fluentd Docker container

Tags: docker, fluentd, health-check

Is there a simple command to use with Docker `HEALTHCHECK` directive to verify sanity of [fluentd container](https://hub.docker.com/r/fluent/fluentd/)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? If your configuration is incorrect, the container will simply exit.